# How should I know what I have already achieved in my last workplace?

Tags: resume

So I have watched this video about resume mistakes:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9tdyZWbGWO0

and read the article about the resume mistakes:

https://www.forbes.com/sites/lizryan/2017/07/22/the-five-worst-resume-mistakes-and-how-to-fix-them/#48f86f4f2741

In one of their point, they always focus on the point that "never write your daily task. write the impact from your daily task"

How can I know what impact that I create when I do the daily task? And is it really boring to read only the daily task in your resume? If so, what should I write in the experience section? Because I don't think I had anything that makes an impact on my last job experiences, even though I already work in several places.

Comment: What is your current job and workplace like? Having these would help provide you with more relevant examples.

Answer (score 5):

If your daily tasks really had no impact, then you can write daily tasks. However, writing only daily tasks will make it look like you've made no real impact at your previous companies.

Some examples.

Programming -- you could say you write code, and unit tests as your daily tasks... Or you could say that you created a medical image viewer that was installed in thousands of hospitals across the country -- and specifically that you created the colonoscopy function.

Sales -- you could say that you make cold calls, and occasionally work events. Or you could say that you landed one of your company's largest accounts for the year, and brought in over $2,000,000 in sales.

Fastfood -- you could say that you made orders, and brought it out to customers, or you could say that you managed to reduce drive-thru time by over 30%.

It is really just how you frame the information.

Comment: Right, there is a difference between "sweeping the floor" and "keeping the floor clean", between "answering the phone" and "ensuring customers get the help they need" -- and trivial as it sounds, knowing the purpose of your tasks, and how they affect the whole company, is important to you and your company. I much prefer resumes that indicate an awareness of this truth. After all, a programmer presses keys on the keyboard all day but none of us list that on the resume!

Answer (score 0):

It is usually not about what impact it IS making but more about what impact YOU THINK it is making. Like your daily task could be writing reports but those reports (with contribution from several other employees) could be helping making some million dollar sales for the company. You may never know whether that report actually ended up in a sale or not but whether do you know what is the potential those reports have.

Idea is to be honest about what you are telling but still keeping the bigger picture in mind. Examples given in the above answers are good way to frame this bigger picture!